# Table width not respected using HTML 1.0 transitional

Tags: html, html-table, width, cells

*EDIT: Remember your COLSPANS. Thanks Lynel Hudson.*

It seems I can't get my table to respect widths. Here's my code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

```
<head>

</head>

<body>

    <table width="480px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" bgcolor="#EFA8D6" align="center">
        <tr width="480px" height="200px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" bgcolor="#EFA8D6" align="left" valign="middle">
            <td width="480px" height="200px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" bgcolor="#EFA8D6" align="left" valign="middle" *EDIT: colspan="3" /EDIT*>
                <img src="http://vixi.com/sites/default/files/imagecache/Frontpage/RawFood.jpg" style="display:block;" border="0" width="480px" height="200px"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr width="480px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" bgcolor="#EFA8D6" align="left" valign="middle">
            <td width="20px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" bgcolor="red" align="left" valign="middle" style="font-size:10px;">
                &nbsp;
            </td>

            <td width="440px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" align="left" valign="middle" style="font-size:20px;">
                Stuff
            </td>

            <td width="20px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" bgcolor="#000000" align="left" valign="middle" style="font-size:10px;">
                &nbsp;
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>
```

Now when you take the second row out from the code, the table's overall width is respected. However, adding in the second row and it's three data cells breaks the width to a certain extent.

It seems that, on the second row, the widths for my two side-cells with blank text (`&nbsp;`) are not having their widths respected.

I have tried `table-layout:fixed` and `auto`, it does not work.

Also, I know inline styling in the HTML element tags is frowned upon, but is required for this particular piece of code for reasons. I am sorry for that inconvenience.

Comment: You might want to try validating that XHTML. It has rather a lot of errors in it. http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Sure, let me work on that and I'll update with the corrected code.

Comment: You seem to be abusing tables for layout. Don't do that. You haven't managed to make it work and it is massively complex when you just want a container of a given width holding an image with some content below it which has margins..

Comment: I realize tables and inline css is not the ideal method, but it needs to be this way. These are for reasons I am not sure I can say.

EDIT: I would not be here if I were not using tables / html1.0

Comment: So, the issue has been fixed per another answer (`colspan=3` in my first TD), but I'm now concerned with the markup validation. It seems that it had problems taking any styling code not inside a `style=" "` tag, but those that those that are not are still rendered correctly. Is there any sort of foreseable actual consequence with leaving the code the way it is now?

Comment: Code validation is just to let users of your website know your site is complaint with the latest standards. There are no actual consequences.

Comment: @user149159 — Aside from the places where the attributes are simply wrong and will be ignored by browsers so removing them will do nothing by make your code easier to read, and for the sprinkling of "px" in all your widths and heights, I don't see anything that is invalid when I eyeball it.

Comment: Are you saying the use of px is annoying / wrong? Or just an observation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have only 1 table cell in your first row, and 3 in your second row. The top row expands to accommodate those 3 cells. Add `colspan="3"` to your first table cell in your first row to fix the width problem.

```html
<head>

</head>

<body>

    <table width="480px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" bgcolor="#EFA8D6" align="center">
        <tr width="480px" height="200px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" bgcolor="#EFA8D6" align="left" valign="middle">
            <td width="480px" height="200px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" bgcolor="#EFA8D6" align="left" valign="middle" colspan="3">
                <img src="http://vixi.com/sites/default/files/imagecache/Frontpage/RawFood.jpg" style="display:block;" border="0" width="480px" height="200px"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr width="480px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" bgcolor="#EFA8D6" align="left" valign="middle">
            <td width="20px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" bgcolor="red" align="left" valign="middle" style="font-size:10px;">
                &nbsp;
            </td>

            <td width="440px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" align="left" valign="middle" style="font-size:20px;">
                Stuff
            </td>

            <td width="20px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" bgcolor="#000000" align="left" valign="middle" style="font-size:10px;">
                &nbsp;
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>
```

Using inline CSS styles and tables for layout is usually a bad idea, which is probably a contributing factor into why you have had this problem.

Comment: Oh dang... you are god.